# Node js and Socket.io Problems

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

First of all i've done some tutorials like: 
https://socket.io/docs/
&
http://www.programwitherik.com/getting-started-with-socket-io-node-js-and-express/
& 
a chat tutorial which i closed already so no link there.

But for all of them its the same. The Folder node_modules exists, the server is running (named app.js or index.js) and the index.html opens. But in every version and every test i dont get it to communicate from client to server. In one of these many questions here wrote someone about a funny installation path. So could it be that something is missing or installed in the wrong folder, needs extra permission or something like that?!

I also installed nodejs new, setup a path like others did in users/apps/ but also the same problems. Where could i find out what went wrong?! Is there a way to trace if the server got all files at the right point?!

The codes are verry basic, just hello world stuff. So i wonder why this wont work.

EDIT:
There is no very special code to share with you. Its the basic! 
Server (app.js)

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
var io = require('socket.io')(app);
var fs = require('fs');

app.listen(80);

function handler (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading index.html');
    }

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Client (index.html)

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io('http://localhost');
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  });
</script>
```

And in my case just for this one sample from the socket.io docs its the port. If i change it to 1337 it would refuse the connection. (just testing with crome without any changes in the browser or something like that) I will also test things like

```
var socket = io();
```

and many other things i read while searching about the solution. So maybe it helps other guys while they follow steps in tutorials where the port was changed without making it usable or open it. I think that was all the time the problem.
Im courious about how others have managed it, while writing a doc or tutorial about it but not one was going to tell that it could not work when there is something wrong with the port. Anyway, i'll update this with an edit2 - 3 and so on for the other tutorials i've made and will add also how it works with other ports, if nobody else do it here.

EDIT 2:
Works also perfectly fine now:

```
var socket = io();

<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
```

and also

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Folders also work now:
Without

```
res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');

/app
 |- app.js
 |- index.js
 |node_modules
 ||- socket.io
 ||- express
```

also

```
res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/index.html');

/app
 |- app.js
 |node_modules
 ||- socket.io
 ||- express
 |client
 ||- assets
 ||- img
 ||- js
 |server
 ||- js
```

Thanks to all who wanted to help.

Comment: I had to split because of the "links"
I tried also to workarount by using this: 
<script src="https://cdn-orig.socket.io/socket.io-1.7.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
But also in this case i get the message:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
or with using an absolute path to socket.io-client:
<script src="127.0.0.1:4200/socket-app/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
i got this one: 
GET http://127.0.0.1:4200/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LhysX8H 404 (Not Found)

Comment: You are missing `http://` or `https://` in your script paths. Fix that and you will probably not get the 404 anymore

Comment: That cannot be the missing thing:
<script src="http://127.0.0.1:4200/socket-app/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
GET http://127.0.0.1:4200/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Lhy-YvY 404 (Not Found)
The http is there but not shown here, dont know why this happens. But ive used it

Comment: We can only help you if you show us the exact code you are trying to use, both client and server.  Paste it into your question and format it properly.  We can probably help you within minutes if you show us the code!

Comment: Update/Edit for the main question with some information about the code.

Comment: There are 2 places where the communication might fail 1) io.on('connection' ...) does not get a connection or socket.emit('news' ...) is not received by the client. Have you confirmed which one fails? You can check this by adding a console.log between the two and seeing if that is executed.

Comment: It was the connection, while connecting on a closed port. Now all those tutorials run like they should. Fine! I changed again what i've done before with a closed port. So i think i can move on and dont need to test two or three tutorials more that i've made yesterday to figure out if there is something wrong with the codes, maybe to old files or bugs in new ones.